# Problems with simple radio button and JavaScript quiz

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

The following simple quiz is not working as expected for me. When I check a radio button, no text colours changes happen to the span text.

I am not sure where the issues are with my code. I am great with HTML and CSS, but am still improving my JavaScript skills.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

[Example quiz on CodePen](https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/wvWBzPa)

```
<input type="radio" name="form[quiz]" value="correct" id="quiz0" class="rsform-radio"><label for="quiz0">Sight</label><span>Correct</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="form[quiz]" value="incorrect" id="quiz1" class="rsform-radio"><label for="quiz1">Smell</label><span>Incorrect</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="form[quiz]" value="incorrect" id="quiz2" class="rsform-radio"><label for="quiz2">Hearing</label><span>Incorrect</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="form[quiz]" value="incorrect" id="quiz3" class="rsform-radio"><label for="quiz3">Taste</label><span>Incorrect</span>

var radioNames = document.getElementsByName("form[quiz]");
for (var i = 0; i < radioNames.length; i++) {
    var radiosValue = radioNames[i];
    if (radiosValue.checked) {
        if (radiosValue.value == "correct") {
            radiosValue.nextSibling.style.color = "green";
        } else {
            radiosValue.nextSibling.style.color = "red";
        }
    } else {
        radiosValue.nextSibling.style.color = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work for you!

```
var radioNames = document.getElementsByName("form[quiz]");

radioNames.forEach(radio => {
    radio.addEventListener('change', () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < radioNames.length; i++) {
            var radiosValue = radioNames[i];
            if (radiosValue.checked) {
                if (radiosValue.value == "correct") {
                    radiosValue.nextSibling.style.color = "green";
                } else {
                    radiosValue.nextSibling.style.color = "red";
                }
            } else {
                radiosValue.nextSibling.style.color = "";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a button using `<input type="button" />` and set its onClick event to run the javascript function, before that include the javascript code as a function between the `<script>` tag in `<head>`.

Comment: I am not wanting to use a button for a click event. Checking a radio button should be enough to show the user if they have chosen a correct or incorrect answer.